Texture satellite images to a sphere (Earth)
I'm tasked with animating satellite images on a sphere (Earth). The satellite images are full disk images from a geostationary satellite, like the ones you can see at https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/GOES/fulldisk.php?sat=G18. But I am new to Blender and 3D rendering in general, so any ideas and suggestions are very appreciated:

Is Blender the right tool to do this?
How could I map every pixels onto the sphere? Should I re-project images to Equirectangular projection (Plate Carrée) first?


I think that the Nasa has flat (mercator) pictures of the earth, but if you absolutely need to use these pictures, use the Unwrap > Project from View option?
